# ios simulator build works but real device build fails in flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, compiler-errors, runtime-error

Currently facing some issue with the flutter ios building. then the app is run with `flutter run` for `ios simulator` it works but same fails if a `real device` is connected.

below is the error code.

```
Non-fat binary /Users/x/demo/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/App is not arm64. Running lipo -info:
Non-fat file: /Users/x/demo/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/App is architecture: x86_64
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

architecture is been added but still this issue.

[image]

Also, I did try installing `pod` or updating it but still no benefits of the same.

Edit: Flutter Doctor image attached.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error must be because of signing capabilities. Try to run the project from xcode.

Follow the steps:

Step 1: Open the ios folder of your project to find Runner.xcworkspace. It should look like this:

[image]

Step 2: When the xcode opens, click on Runner on the top left corner of the window.

[image]

Step 3: Go to Signing and Capabilities and under the "Team" dropdown, select a field. If none exists, create an account.

[image]

Step 4: In the "Bundle Identifier", your app's bundle name should be showing. Add .app in the end. For example, if its "com.example.yourapp" make it "com.example.yourapp.app" and press enter.

Press the play button on the top left to run the app on the selected device.

---

If it doesn't work,

Change the flutter target runner in xcode - build active architecture only: yes

[image]

Comment: everything exists. the app was running properly until a few days back. today I just made some layout changes and bam ! its giving me this issue :(

Comment: Clean the current build using flutter clean and then run again.

Comment: Can u attach a screenshot of flutter doctor along with the question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206088/discussion-between-princeoo7-and-yudhishthir-singh).